# Should database connections be mocked?

Tags: database, testing, mocking

I'm trying to apply unit testing to a project I'm working on. I work with Python an MySQLdb but I think this discussion is language-agnostic.
I want to test a function, let's call it foobar(). It executes SQL queries that look similar to this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a == " +varA+ " AND  b < " +varB)
```

There is a little bit of complexity going on in the function. 
How and how often `cursor.execute(query)` gets called depends on foobar's arguments.

Now I'm unsure if I should mock the database connection `cursor`. 
If I don't, it's bad because the test depends on the availability of a DB server.
If I do, it's bad because the mock has to know which queries will be called. But the exact queries are an implementation detail. E.g. whether the queries are written in lower- or uppercase does not affect the correctness of foobar. But changing that will break the test. The test will also be hard to read because of the somewhat complex mock object.

Is this a case of choosing the lesser evil? Is there a third way?

Comment: So little question only while the topic is that large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you should not mock the cursor or the connection. refactor code and extract this code to a seperate service/repository. there should be a method that takes two parameters `varA` and `varB` and returns list of rows/objects

- in your fast/unit tests you should mock whole repository - check if your method is called with proper parameters (`varA` and `varB`).
- in your slow/integration tests you should check if **your real** database executes this query correctly for all possible `varA` and `varB`

by mocking connection/cursor all you do is simply implementing the database - it's just a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

You've already done a good job in weighing the pros and cons here, but one point to note is that the purpose of testing is to simulate as close to the exact conditions that will be seen in production.

You should avoid mocking the DB connection and let it read from a local MysQL DB instance. Furthermore, ensure the state of the db is reset before each test to ensure test modularity.

The general workflow would be -

1. Before all tests create the schema `myApp_test` if it doesn't already exist.
2. Drop all tables and re-create them from mock data fixtures. You can do this several ways, my favorite is to read fixtures from a YML configuration file and inserts them directly into the DB. (If you're working with a framework like rails, it has pre-built functionality to do this, or there are a host of gems and libraries for other languages that might help with this.)
3. Before each test, call the function in step 2 to reset the DB
4. Run the test

In response to your concern, I don't think it's a concern that it depends on a DB being available, especially locally. If you're running tests, it's not unreasonable to specify that you should have a DB available. Alternatively if you're really concerned about DB availability you can try creating your own locally by using SQLite or other text-based local DB's

Comment: Running unit test against real DB (even if it's a local DB created for testing purposes) makes them slow and brittle.